# Junit 2.0 : Different results for same test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm having different results for the same test in JUnit. The first test seems to be OK and to verify all the assertions, I believe that the class works fine.  Then I rerun the test and I get an assertion failure. I realized that the problem was that I didn't clear the "data" after the test, and I tried to fix it doing exactly that, but I'm still having those assertion failures.

Any ideas?

Unit Test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * The test class TestHistorial.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class TestHistorial extends junit.framework.TestCase {
    Historial hist;

    /**
     * Default constructor for test class TestHistorial
     */
    public TestHistorial() {
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the test fixture.
     * <p/>
     * Called before every test case method.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        hist = new BaseDatos();
    }

    /**
     * Tears down the test fixture.
     * <p/>
     * Called after every test case method.
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        hist.eliminarTodosLosRegistros();
    }

    /**
     * Prueba
     */

    public void testHistorial() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Registro reg = new RegistroTemperatura(273 + i, 1900 + i, i + 1, i + 1, i);
            try {
                hist.agregarRegistro(reg);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                assertEquals(false, true);
            } // No debería llegar aquí.
            String str = "Reg_" + i;
            Registro tReg = hist.getRegistroPorId(str);
            try {
                Temperatura t = new Temperatura(273 + i);
                assertEquals(true, t.equals(((RegistroTemperatura) tReg).getTemperatura()));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                assertEquals(false, true);
            } // No debería llegar aquí.
            try {
                Fecha f = new Fecha(1900 + i, i + 1, i + 1, i);
                assertEquals(true, f.equals(tReg.getFecha()));
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                assertEquals(false, true);
            } // No debería llegar aquí.
        }
        assertEquals(20, hist.getNumeroDeRegistros());
        assertEquals(true, hist.getRegistroMasViejo().equals(new RegistroTemperatura(273, 1900, 1, 1, 0)));

    }
}
```

The output of the test after first testing is:

$> expected: false but was: true

The real question is, is the `tearDown()` method being executed after `testHistorial()``? If 
it isn't, how should I do it?

Comment: why are you catching exceptions? create a separate test and use the `@expected` annotation. This some pretty ugly unit testing, refactor this into multiple tests and it will be a lot easier to determine the fault.

Comment: Ok. Where can i find junit2 documentation?

Comment: You should have only one assert per test, with rare exceptions.  If you have two complex objects that are expected to be equal, and you want to report which fields differ, use the `ErrorCollector @Rule`, and collect the assertion exceptions.  The current version of JUnit is 4.11.  Get it at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install.

Comment: If you want to fail a test explicitly, call `Assert.fail` with a meaningful message; don't use the `assertEquals(true, false)` hack.  However, if an exception would be unexpected in your test, just have the method throw the exception and don't handle it.  Remove all of the try/catch blocks.  JUnit tests that throw an exception are not considered to have succeeded, and you will get a lot more useful information out of the stacktrace.

Comment: I have a similar junit test problem, can any one help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681501/junit-test-fails-when-run-on-package-but-success-when-run-on-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [don't use any version of JUnit below 4.0.](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started)  Second, don't use anything in `junit.framework.*` or `junit.extensions.*`.

With *that* out of the way...

To answer the first question, in JUnit 4.x, your `@After`-annotated method is always executed after the execution of your test case.

To get to the meat of the problem...your unit tests should be testing one thing.  They're only a unit of functionality.  Right now, you're testing at least five different pieces, which is why it's complicated to understand what's going on, or why it's breaking.

Take it piece by piece:  Test `Registro` and feel confident that it's doing what it should be.  Then move on to `Historial`.   Then move on to `Temperatura`.  Then `Fecha`.  I can't tell you specifically *why* it's giving you inconsistent assertion failures, but I can tell you that it's very difficult to understand what you're actually *testing*, which may be the cause of the misunderstanding.

Also, as generic advice - if you are catching `Exception`, consider only catching it in a test if it's either a checked exception (enforced by Java), or if you need it to throw the exception and need to assert things about the state after the exception is thrown.

Comment: Or if you need to test the exception message.  Then you also use the `ExpectedException @Rule`.  His `@After` method is unnecessary, since every run gets a fresh `Historial`.

Comment: Even if it's a checked exception, unless the exception is expected in your test, don't catch it.  Just add it to the `throws` clause of the method signature.  And if it is expected, consider using the `expected` attribute of the `@Test` annotation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices, i'll refactor the unit test according your recommendations. I beg your pardon for my grammar errors, i studied english but i'm still a little bit rusty, because i don't speak or write english for a while.