# Junit test fails when run on package, but success when run on file

Tags: java, junit, mockito, bamboo

Big update:
Has anyone run into this before?

I'm using JUnit 4.5 and Mockito 1.7 in a Maven project.

I have testCaseA.java in package testCaseFolder.
if I open testCaseA.java, right click in the code, select "Run as" -"Junit test" it is okay. 
But if I right click package, select "Run as" -"Junit test", it will fail:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected!
Somewhere before this line you probably misused Mockito argument matchers.
For example you might have used anyObject() argument matcher outside of verification or stubbing.
Here are examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"));
    at testCaseA.setUP(testCaseA.java:33)
```

Line 33 is: `//MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);***//it said this is error***`

Here is the code:

```
SomeService service;
@Mock
private CommonService commonService;
@Mock
public Errors errors;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);***//it said this is error***
}

@Test
public void testvalidate() {
    //fail even here is empty
}
```

Comment: After some digging, I find the problem, I just don't know why and how to fix. The problem is not the MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  the problem is mock, @Mock private CommonService commonService;  If I don't mock anything, it will be find. If mock here, it go wrong.

Comment: I rolled your edit back, as there was an answer that held context with your original version.  In the future, avoid making edits that invalidate existing answers on questions.  This can lead to others who have a similar issue to be confused as to what your specific error was, and how you were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** 
from the error your getting this should be correct.

Your Mockito.when statement is wrong.

```
Mockito.when(commonService.get(Mockito.eq(contactGroupId))).thenReturn(disseminationProfile);
```

Or

```
Mockito.when(commonService.get(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(disseminationProfile);
```

Comment: no, this doesn't matter, I can comments all the code inside method public void testvalidate(). still will get same error.

Comment: Thank you ohiocowboy, I read that before, it is a stander doc, I did as it says, have problem, so it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Does your test class extend a test class with @Before public void initMocks()

Comment: Hello @ohiocowboy, my test class don't extend a test class with @ before.....it have the @ Before method itself.

Comment: @Jack any reason why your not using Mockito 1.9.5? Also I was messing around using the annotations of Mockito. These in the pas versions were troublesome.

Comment: this is old project, so we still using 1.7

Comment: With that statement I wouldn't use annotations.

Comment: I ask around the other team, they use the same jar, they don't have such problem, so wired. I compare my project with theirs, no different in mockito config. actually, we only need to config in the pom.xml, right?

Comment: config? that only thing I ever did was add the dependency to my pom.xml. Can you update with what you mean by config and also what version of Maven 2 or 3?

Comment: maven2. And yes, pom.xml is the only place I have change. that is why confuse me so much.

Comment: Wild. I think to solve this we need to take a closer look at the 2 classes your Mocking and the Class your testing. btw when you mean test locally do you mean from Eclipse or IDE, or do you mean you run it from maven itself mvn clean test?

Comment: Locally, I mean test in my Eclipse. And no matter which class I mocking, and no matter which test case it it. As long as I have @Mock and MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); in the test case. it will have error on bamboo. But success in my eclipse.

Comment: can you run it locally using maven and not within eclipse? Because that's what Bamboo does correct?

Comment: @Jack can you share the entire test case? Are the mocked services suppose to get injected into SomeService.class?